# mysqli_query not working inside array_map function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Mysqli_query is not working inside array_map function. My code is :

```
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD','yyy');
define('DB_NAME','fff');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

foreach($unique_array as $supplier) 
{
     $urep[]=$supplier['rep_name'];
     $udate[]=$supplier['date'];
$ucid[]=$supplier['cid'];

$unique_arrayyy[] = array('rep_name'=>$supplier['rep_name'], 'date'=>$supplier['date']);
}

array_map(function ($var) {
$fetch_gdd=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from grade");

echo mysqli_num_rows($fetch_gdd); exit;

}, $unique_arrayyy);
```

The $unique_arrayyy includes multidimentional array values. I want to run query inside the array_map fuction. At the time of fetching the row its giving me blank window. Please help.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top of page just after `<?php`  ad also  change like:- `$fetch_gdd=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from grade")or die (mysqli_error($conn));`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the connection available in the scope of your anonymous function, `$conn` is undefined.

```
array_map(function ($var) use ($conn) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ Make $conn available in the function
    $fetch_gdd=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from grade");

    echo mysqli_num_rows($fetch_gdd);
    // don't exit here

}, $unique_arrayyy);
```

Also note that you probably don't want to stop the script in your function, so I have removed the `exit;` statement as well.

Also note that I assume that this is just example code; you don't use `$var` inside your function and if you do the same query every time, you should not do that in the `array_map` function.